# How to see *all* most CPU-consuming processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage, top

The "CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor" applet shows my CPU is running at its maximum most of the time :

[image: CPU Monitor at maximum]

However, the results of the `top` command always show that the top processes are around 2%, as usual.

[image: top - all seems normal]

The System Monitor does not help either :

[image: System Monitor]

So, it seems to me `top` is not showing all CPU-consuming processes. Is there a way to see them all, using `top` or another command?

Notes:

- I do not run any special task on this computer (just Firefox, LibreOffice and a Terminal at the moment).
- The CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor applet is set on Powersave.
- I already tried restarting the computer to see if the problem goes away (it does not).

Update: Result of command `vmstat 1 5`:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 30014208 115912 965100    0    0    14     4   37  143  1  0 98  0  0
 0  0      0 30013956 115912 965100    0    0     0     0  179  392  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 30013956 115920 965100    0    0     0    24  159  280  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 30010932 115920 965100    0    0     0   200  313  989  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 30010932 115920 965104    0    0     0     0  157  316  0  0 99  0  0
```

**Edit:** The CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor problem apparently disappeared, after 14 months. I suppose some system update fixed it.

Comment: CPU frequency does not translate to CPU usage.

Comment: @planetmaker Does that mean the CPU would run at maximum speed for no real use? That sounds like a bug in the system to me.

Comment: What is the result of `vmstat 1 5`?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov I don't know how to make it fit in this comment, so here it is: https://pastebin.com/Z37Gq2bE

Comment: Do not add new information as comments – instead, [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1737087/edit). // CPU frequency scaling is a complex topic that depends on many factors. The CPU load certainly is one of these. Consider that there could also be a difference between CPU usage accounting and CPU frequency reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the result of `vmstat` your machine is sleeping:

```
 0  0      0 30010932 115920 965100    0    0     0   200  313  989  1  0 99  0  0
```

The idle time is 99% from the processor, only 1% is loaded. And quoting one comment:

> CPU frequency scaling is a complex topic that depends on many factors.
> The CPU load certainly is one of these. Consider that there could also
> be a difference between CPU usage accounting and CPU frequency
> reporting.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that all is fine then, and that I don't have to try to fix the machine? It is not abnormally wasting energy?

Comment: @Georg, these MHz can be wrong, bug, race condition, etc. You may check a lot of things like machine temperature, fans of processor, fans of box, etc before conclude high energy consumption.